# Tag for two-factor authentication

Tags: discussion, tags

A tag for it was created today: https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/34355/revisions

I find `2fa` not very clear. It's that it was in the question's title or I wouldn't have understood at first. Should we change this to the (rather long) two-factor-authentication? Or perhaps multi-factor authentication (regardless of two or three)?

And I haven't looked yet, but more posts might need this tag. If I were to tag some posts as 2fa now and we then change (or alias) the name of the tag, I assume all posts will be changed with it?

**Edit:** Oh, actually, there is a tag. That would make `2fa` obsolete anyway: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-factor

I suppose this topic can be closed; I'll retag the post.

Comment: Thanks. If more questions start using that tag (and the tag doesnt get cleaned up), I can push it as a synonym of multi-factor.